# Is it a bad practice to have resources without a controller or views? (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I have one resource that is only a model: I am building a an app which has a similar thing to the Twitter timeline and mentions system. The mentions class has not a correspondent controller or any views. The way I built it, mentions are created whenever a message is posted. Before the message being created, it is scanned for usernames and creates a mention instance for each one of them. This happens all in the messages and mentions models.
Or is this model-only situation fine for those resources with which users dont interact directly?

This is my first rails app, and I am still learning MVC and REST, so I guess I am doing a lot of things wrong. What would be a proper architecture for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have data that doesn't need a separate controller or view, then that's just the way your app is.

That said, it's often handy to expose even nested models via a RESTful mapping (if you app requires it) to avoid over-eager fetching--but again, whether or not that makes sense is app-specific.

Comment: I dont really understand that last part ('That said, it's often handy to expose even nested models via a RESTful mapping (if you app requires it) to avoid over-eager fetching'). Would you care to elaborate a bit?

Comment: @oalo Sure. You might want to retrieve messages via a REST API. You wouldn't necessarily want to return that messages' mentions in the same call, since the caller might not want them (or for efficiency). But if you *need* to expose them, they could be retrieved via a second call to `message/:id/mentions`, which would probably be handled in a `Mention` controller.

Answer (score 2):

I have worked on many projects where there are Models that are being used as Join tables and do not have corresponding Controllers or Views.  Sounds like that's what you are doing here so I wouldn't worry about it.

Sometimes you will have a Controller and Views without having a corresponding Model for them, and vice versa.